# Rails fields_for ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that has some nested fields - ie. User accepts_nested_attributes_for Class.

Class has an end_date datetime field.

I'd like to order the classes by end_date in the editing form. The form has something like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :classes do |builder| %>
  <%= render "class_fields", {:f => builder} %>
<% end %>
```

Obviously, they come out in order of the created_at field.

How can I modify this to order them by an arbitrary field?

Comment: what is in 'class_fields'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want classes sorted that way, you can add an :order option to your association. If not, fields_for takes a second argument that's the record(s) to display, so you can pass in your list in whatever order you want.

Comment: Postgres, as an example, returns things in near random order unless you ask for a specific ordering. MySQL sometimes defaults to order of insertion.